# Is it possible to remove controls from HTML default player (<video />) without not removing keyboard support?

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

I want to make a custom video player in React.
So I removed the `controls` attribute from the `<video />` tag, this solves the problem of hiding nativ controls and making my own. But want it to still support native keyboard controls.

Please make sure the solution works on most of the browsers, it should not be webkit specifix.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css file:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none;
}
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/TheKetan2/3ba4t2ux/1/

Comment: This is not a solution, what about hiding in firefox and opera and IE.